# Collecting tweets with premium api based on geocode

Tags: python, api, twitter

I want to collect tweets based on the following parameters: query, language, to and from date, geocode(location). So far I've been using the standard API and tweepy with python and it worked perfectly.
Now i need to collect older tweets and wish to purchase the premium api. But I want to be able to use the api with python itself.
I tried tweepy, searchtweets and twitterAPI but none of them had all the functionality(geocode is missing in searchtweets) I required.

How can I use the premium api and search tweets based on geocode?

Comment: What is missing in searchtweets-python in terms of geocode?  Are you forming the query with valid operators? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/premium-operators

Comment: rule = gen_rule_payload("elections",
                        from_date="2020-07-12",
                        to_date="2020-07-15",
                        geocode='33.5206824,-86.8024326,25mi'
                       )

is giving me the error gen_rule_payload() got an unexpected keyword argument 'geocode'
could you tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Per the documentation I linked above, there is no "geocode" operator for premium search, but you can use the bounding_box or point_radius operators. Premium search is not the same syntax as standard legacy search.

Comment: I believe searchtweets is a little different from the docs you shared because according to the link, fromDate and toDate is the right way. But that doesn't work with searchtweets and instead from_date and to_date works just fine. I also tried bounding_box but in vain. I shall try point_radius

Comment: You need to put the values into the rule `”elections point_radius:[33.52 -86.80 25]”`, not outside of it. Per the documentation I shared, the dates are not included as part of the search rule.